# Wrong function syntax while encapsulating StatefulWidget

Tags: flutter, dart

I create a custom flutter widget that is a ListTile containing a title + a SegmentedButton, so that it is easy to keep it consistent through the whole app.

I use a StatefulWidget (needed for other features) and I wrote this :

```dart
class SegmentedButtonTile<T> extends StatefulWidget
{
    final Widget title;
    final List<ButtonSegment<T>> segments;
    final Set<T> selected;
    final void Function(Set<T>)? onSelectionChanged;
    
    // And then constructor etc...
}

class _SegmentedButtonTileState<T> extends State<SegmentedButtonTile<T>>
{
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context)
    {
        return ListTile(
            title: widget.title,
            trailing: SegmentedButton<T>(
                segments: widget.segments,
                selected: widget.selected,
                onSelectionChanged: widget.onSelectionChanged
            )
        );
    }
    
    // And init(), dispose(), etc...
}
```

It gives me this exception :

> _TypeError (type '(Set) => void' is not a subtype of type '((Set) => void)?')

Alright, I worked on custom SwitchTile widget before and other widgets dealing with "parent" widget function, so I write this :

```dart
class _SegmentedButtonTileState<T> extends State<SegmentedButtonTile<T>>
{
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context)
    {
        return ListTile(
            title: widget.title,
            trailing: SegmentedButton<T>(
                segments: widget.segments,
                selected: widget.selected,
                onSelectionChanged: (Set<T> newSelection) => widget.onSelectionChanged!(newSelection)
            )
        );
    }
    
    // And init(), dispose(), etc...
}
```

And still the same issue...

For information, how I call it :

```dart
SegmentedButtonTile<CorrectionMethod>(
    title: Text("Correction method"),
    segments: const <ButtonSegment<CorrectionMethod>>[
        ButtonSegment<CorrectionMethod>(
            value: CorrectionMethod.heartRate,
            label: Text("Heart rate")
        ),
        ButtonSegment<CorrectionMethod>(
            value: CorrectionMethod.rrInterval,
            label: Text("Interval")
        )
    ],
    selected: <CorrectionMethod>{bloc.state.method},
    onSelectionChanged: (Set<CorrectionMethod> newMethod) => bloc.add(CorrectionMethodChanged(method: newMethod.first)),
)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you include how are you declaring your `createState`? It should look something like `State<SegmentedButtonTile<T>> createState() => _SegmentedButtonTileState()`.

Comment: Yes exactly like that, except I call _SegmentedButtonTileState<T>()

Comment: Does replacing the tear-off `onSelectionChanged: widget.onSelectionChanged` with a lambda `onSelectionChanged: (value) => widget.onSelectionChanged(value)` work?

Comment: No I already did that (see 2nd case in my post)